# Connecting my Arduino with Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, bluetooth

What I want to do is to create a temperature measurement bracelet that you wear on your wrist.
So it takes data from the sensors and sends them to the PC.
What I am using to do that:

- an Arduino Uno
- a temperature sensor
- a Bluetooth module to connect with Arduino Uno
- a mobile phone
- a PC

I will connect Arduino Uno with the Bluetooth module so it sends data to the mobile for example.
Since I am a beginner I do not have it very clear. Do I need a GPRS SIM (SIM900A for example or whatever) for this to function or just the Bluetooth connection is enough?

Specify that the question is very basic because I am a beginner.

Comment: You’d be better off with something like [Adafruit’s Bluefruit Feather LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2829?gclid=CjwKCAiAx57RBRBkEiwA8yZdUD-iys8bKTcay8Xmnijpnp0CB7dQ7rhC6HootlS-j94fPusFeYQGDRoC3T0QAvD_BwE). It has a smaller foot print and a pre-programmed BLE chip on board that you interact with via UART & AT commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need the Bluetooth module, not a Sim card.  The HC-05 and HC-06 are Bluetooth modules that are commonly used with Arduinos, are relatively inexpensive, are fairly small, and there's quite a bit of documentation out there on how to use them.

Comment: Ok. I agree but this module can be used in a arduino just to improvise. But to create the real bracalet wouldn't it be a little bit innaproporiate to integrate Bluetooth module in it?

Comment: It might be a little big for a bracelet, but it could work.  Some Arduino Nanos come with BLE built-in, but watch out for the one's that say they do but don't.  I bought 5 from China with the description saying it had BLE built-in, but I couldn't find how to enable it or the chip/antenna on the board.  The Nano or a smaller Arduino would work fine in a bracelet.  Some Smart watches are huge, so a large bracelet isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: The idea is that Bluetooth  and SIM can be substitute of one another?

Comment: Yes and no.  Both can allow wireless communication, but in different ways.  With a sim card, you could cut out the phone entirely and connect to the PC more directly, but it's likely to cost you for the service.  It may also pull more power than the Bluetooth module, but I don't have any specific examples on that, as I haven't used a sim card.

Comment: But Bluetooth cannoct send data to laptop directly too? Without using mobile?

Comment: If your PC/laptop has a Bluetooth module, it can.  However, Bluetooth only has a range of about 30 ft., without extra gear to extend the range.  The likely device to usually be within range of your bracelet is your phone.  Granted, you can store your data on the bracelet until you get in range of your PC, which is what many off-the-shelf bracelets do.  A sim card wouldn't let you directly connect at all.  The sim card would basically give you access to the internet and allow you to post to a website, not your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mobile device to which you are connected by bluetooth is always kept near the bracelet, you don't need a GPRS module. The mobile device, then, would use it's network connection (either GPRS, LTE, WiFi, etc.) to communicate the data to the PC for processing or storage.